# Base live update in Postgres

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, plotly-dash

Base live update in Postgres

Hello guys.
I have a Postgres database where I create my dataframe.
So my graphics work, my calculations work, almost everything is beautiful.
The only problem is that if the database changes I need to stop the Flask service and restart, only then my dashboard is updated.
I tried a lot before coming back here with this answer.

I'm taking a beating with update database.
I can't get dash to update my charts and tables by itself.
I tried on other forums but was not successful.
I'll post my code here updated and minimized.
There will be two links to the drive, one with the postgres database and the other with the code.
the code is relatively small the part that doesn't work properly.

I will send you two links:
1 - Containing the complete code:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c0e8UelUgGVx_IrWLFncwc2JRPraUS79/view?usp=share_link

I have a few observations for this code to work:
a) Install the libraries highlighted in the teste.py file before the imports.
b) The database access configuration I made in a file called pg_config.json, just edit and inform your bank credentials.

2 - Containing the Postgres database:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fwrc0xAMfVnv0_lUSHjNTO3HnQIkUvHN/view?usp=sharing

teste.py is a table that gets information from df_data_generals

Comment: Hi, did you try to use Interval: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval

Answer (score 1):

I did something like below with mysql. Please refer it and check does it match your requirment.

```
    dcc.Store(id='store-data', data=[], storage_type='memory'), # 'local' or 'session'    
    dcc.Interval(id='update', n_intervals = 0, interval=1000*30)
])
    
@app.callback(Output('store-data','data'),
             [Input('update', 'n_intervals')])

def update_data(n):
    global jobs_2
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",              
        user="root",            
        password="",        
        database="indeed_data_dump")   

    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM jobs")
    columns = [col[0] for col in mycursor.description]
    data = mycursor.fetchall()
    jobs_2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    db.close()
    jobs_2.to_dict()
```